# LogonUI.exe exception preventing Windows 10 from booting

Tags: windows, windows-10

When I boot Windows 10, just before the login screen should appear, I now get the following error dialogue:

```
LogonUI.exe - Application Error
The exception Illegal Instruction
An attempt was made to execute an illegal instruction.
(0xc000001d) occurred in the application at location
0x00007FFA27D94428

Click on OK to terminate the program
Click on CANCEL to debug the program
```

Clicking either option just gives me a short wait before the dialogue reappears.

If I **forcibly** shut down the computer, and immediately boot it again, I can log in as normal. This does not work if I safely turn it off.

I have recently performed a clean install of Windows 10, and have activated BitLocker on my hard drive. I'm afraid I honestly cannot remember if I performed any successful boots after reinstalling, before this error began appearing.

Where can I go from here to solve this?

Comment: I believe you could give it a try to contact MS support on this one (they have a free support chat). Did you try to reinstall the system?

Comment: I may have just got to the bottom of it - disabling Hyper-V seems to have done the trick! It also, bizarrely, seems to have made me unable to change my screen brightness...