# How to obtain a safe replacement Windows executable

Tags: windows, windows-10

I wish to replace a system file (specifically LogonUI.exe), and traditionally would have done this using a WIndows installation CD and a command such as

```
expand d:\i386\logonui.ex_ %windir%\system32\logonui.exe
```

However, as I have no installation media for Windows 10, is there a legal and safe way of obtaining a "vanilla" copy?

Comment: Why can't you just download the Windows 10 .ISO?  Microsoft makes it available to all Windows users [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench) or by using the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).  Why do you believe the current file needs to be replaced?

Comment: Because I didn't realise they make the ISO available, thank you. I'm unsure if it needs replacing but am trying to fix [this issue](http://superuser.com/questions/1005267/logonui-exe-exception-preventing-windows-10-from-booting) and am trying everything I can think of at this point

Comment: Have you tried running the System File Checker yet (`sfc /scannow')? It exists to identify and replace corrupted/missing system files...

Comment: I have, it's found an issue with opencl.dll which I am simultaneously trying to work out how to fix!

Comment: @tsvallender - `OpenCL.dll` would be connected to your display drivers and any program that specifically installs it.  Your [OpenCL.dll](http://superuser.com/questions/1002516/sfc-scannow-unable-to-repair-corrupt-component-store/1002606#1002606) problem is something we can help you with.

Comment: I have tried updating the display driver to no avail, attempting to replace the dll manually was going to be my next step, what would you suggest?

Comment: I linked to the detailed solution to your OpenCL.dll problem.

Comment: I may have just got to the bottom of it - disabling Hyper-V seems to have done the trick! It also, bizarrely, seems to have made me unable to change my screen brightness...